# Terraform - how to use the same load balancer between multiple AWS ecs_service resources?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs

I had a question about creating a service on AWS ECS using Terraform, and would appreciate any and all feedback, especially since I'm an AWS newbie.

I have several services in the same cluster (each service is a machine learning model). The traffic isn't that high, so I would like the same load balancer to route requests to the different services (based on a request header which specifies the model to use).

I was trying to create the services using Terraform (https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ecs_service) but I'm having a hard time understanding the load_balancer configuration. There is no option to choose the ARN or ID of a specific load balancer, which makes me think that a separate Load Balancer is created for each service - and that sounds expensive :)

Has anyone had any experience with this, who can tell me what is wrong with my reasoning?

Thanks a lot for reading!

Answer (score 3):

Fred, in the link to the documentation you've posted is the answer, let me walk you through it.

Here is how two ECS services can use a one Application Load Balancer Graphically:

[image: ECS Services with one Load Balancer]

The below scenario describes the configuration for one of the services, it is analogous for a second one, the only thing you wouldn't need to repeat is the Load Balancer declaration.

You can define the following:

```
# First let's define the Application LB
resource "aws_lb" "unique" {
  name               = "unique-lb"
  internal           = false
  load_balancer_type = "application"
  ... #the rest of the config goes here
}

#Now let's create the target group for the service one
resource "aws_lb_target_group" "serviceonetg" {
  name     = "tg-for-service-one"
  port     = 8080 #example value
  protocol = "HTTP"
  ...  #the rest of the config goes here
}

#Now create the link between the LB and the Target Group
# also will add a rule when to forward the traffic using HTTP path /serviceone
resource "aws_alb_listener" "alb_serviceone_listener" {  
  load_balancer_arn = aws_alb.unique.arn # Here is the LB ARN 
  port              = 80
  protocol          = "HTTP"
  
  default_action {    
    target_group_arn = "${aws_alb_target_group.serviceonetg.arn}" #Here is the TG ARN
    type             = "forward"  
  }

  condition {    
    field  = "path-pattern"    
    values = ["/serviceone"]  
  }
}

#As a last step, you need to link your service with the target group.
resource "aws_ecs_service" "service_one" {
  ...  # prior configuration goes here
  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.serviceonetg.arn # Here you will link the service with the TG
    container_name   = "myservice1"
    container_port   = 8080
  }
  ...  #the rest of the config goes here
}
```

As a side note, I would template the repeating part for the services using data structures in a way you can use `count` or `for_each` to describe Target Group, Listeners and Services only once and leaving templating engine do the rest. Basically, follow the DRY principle.

I hope this can help you.